# I try to solve this issue but no way

Tags: reactjs, typescript

[image: The argument of the type "element" cannot be assigned to the parameter of the type "string".]

typeScript- ReactJs : as you can see I get the following Error : The argument of the type "element" cannot be assigned to the parameter of the type "string : on line

`children.push(<Option key={i.toString(36) + i}>{i.toString(36) + i}</Option>)`

```
import { Row, Col, Select, Button, Card } from "antd";
import React, { FC } from "react";

const Option = Select.Option;
const children: string[] = [];
for (let i = 10; i < 36; i++) {
    children.push(<Option key={i.toString(36) + i}>{i.toString(36) + i}</Option>);
}
```

Comment: didn't downvote, but please avoid picture of code and if you have to, make sure the picture is readable,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you are trying to push jsx inside of your array which is typed as `string[]` so you need to change the type of the array to `React.ReactNode[]`

```
import { Row, Col, Select, Button, Card } from "antd";
import React, { FC } from "react";

const Option = Select.Option;
const children: React.ReactNode[] = [];
for (let i = 10; i < 36; i++) {
    children.push(<Option key={i.toString(36) + i}>{i.toString(36) + i}</Option>);
}
```